# Chat reputation inbox bug

Tags: bug, reputation, chat, global-inbox

This bug annoys me a lot.

> [image: animation of inbox notification reappearing]

This is a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: A gif can't be paused like a video can

Comment: And why do you need to pause it?

Comment: So nosy people can see how much rep I earned yesterday

Comment: And what's so unique in creating multiple accounts a day? :)

Comment: Just trying to find stupid bugs. Like this!

Comment: Wait, that's what I do. You are hijacking my relay! :P

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't consider it to be the bug; the top bar is cached on non-SE 2.0 sites, which are the chat system and Area 51. The rep or achievements and inbox messages you've already read come away in a few minutes, for me in two, and doesn't really annoy me.

So, unless the chat system becomes a full-featured SE 2.0 site, which is technically not possible, this bug has almost zero chances to be fixed.

Comment: ARRRGH! MORE CACHING?

Comment: @Uni lol, yes. Not my fault though :D

Comment: Anyways I'll wait for a dev to see this and fix it

Comment: Why is chat not going to become a SE 2.0 site?

Comment: @Uni Because it's not the usual SE site. You don't vote, don't post answers or questions, don't comment there, in other words, it's a **completely different system**. Instead ,you can post messages, create and manage rooms, star, etc. SE 2.0 sites are the ones you see [there](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: @UniKitty Doesn't mean it can't be improved though, and repeat notifications is a bit "buggy" imo. Even if status-bydesign, the design needs tweaking :)

Comment: This is, at best, a non-answer... all you're saying is the bug is unlikely to be fixed. That's comment territory... no answer needed.