# Achievement and inbox dropdowns aren't cleared after clicking, on https://stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

When going to any page of https://stackexchange.com with a new reputation gain, the achievements drop-down keeps showing a new badge green highlight:

[image: Badge indicator highlighted]

And then trying to dismiss the notification by clicking on it gets rid of the green badge notification, but the +5 remains even after I've clicked away from the drop-down.

Even the inbox count does not disappear after clicking somewhere else.

[image: GIF of the bug]

Comment: Related (?): [Chat reputation inbox bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259638/295232)

Comment: I was about to report this; it’s still an issue. Exactly the same thing happens for notifications. The top bar icons just never get updated on https://stackexchange.com, except after a refresh. I even recorded a screencast.

Comment: The only way to fix it is to visit another site from the profile, or to click on the place where you gained the reputation.

Answer (score 6):

This issue should be fixed now.

Comment: Shiyao Li, is this too fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259638?

Comment: @RandomPerson I'm not sure if this bug is related to the bug reported in this ticket. We'll check it out and get back to you.