# Reputation +n doesn't disappear from the achievements after reading it

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stackexchange.com, achievements-dialog

I got +n reputation, while I was searching a question in the SE search. I clicked the achievements icon to make it disappear, but it didn't:

Received +2:

[image]

Clicked achievement dialog:

[image]

Clicked out of the dialog to close:

[image]

The +2 remains and the green background has disappeared. However, after a reboot it disappears.

Worth noting it happens only on `stackexchange.com/*`.

Comment: same thing happens for inbox notifications

Comment: Duplicate of [Achievements dropdown is broken on SE.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306452/289905); and it’s _not_ fixed, @JNat.

Comment: By "it's not fixed" do you mean that post isn't [tag:status-completed], or that you're actually able to still repro the bug, @user289905?

Comment: @JNat I, and also [other users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354096/289905), can still reproduce the bug. I guess, the [tag:status-completed] tag also shouldn’t be applied, so maybe both.

Comment: It's not restrictive to stackexchange.com It happened on Math.SE too.

Comment: Marking this as completed again, since it appears to have been addressed in the meantime.

Comment: @JNat it's still not fixed, I'm still seeing the problem with both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! <s>I deployed a fix for this issue on SE.com. It should be fixed now.</s> <s>It's waiting to be deployed right now.</s> The fix is deployed now :)

Comment: Is the inbox count too fixed? [Achievement and inbox dropdowns aren't cleared after clicking, on https://stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306452)

Comment: Sorry, we changed the deployment system and it looks like the deployment hasn't made it to production yet. We're looking into it and will update this question soon.

Comment: @ShiyaoLi so technically it is now status planned (to be deployed)?

Comment: @Luuklag Yes I just changed the tag. Thanks!

Comment: @RandomPerson Just replied to that post. The inbox count is fixed as well.