# Bug in Achievements Icon in the Network Profile

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile, achievements-dialog

This behaviour was noted in Google Chrome. I was in the Network Profile page when got +10 in a specific community

[image: Network Profile with +10 Achievement]

Then, clicked in the "Achievements" icon and clicked again. This usually is enough to have the geen icon with +10 to disappear. As that wasn't enough, clicked in it again and then right click and opened the question that was upvoted in a different tab (as you can see in the next image, that item was clicked as it doesn't appear with a darker background color and the green icon is still in there)

[image: +10 Achievement is still there]

In order for that green icon with the number 10 to disapear I had to go to a different page in that same tab. If I did that and went back again, the green icon would still be there.

Comment: I don't follow what the exact problem is.

Comment: @Luuklag the green icon remains / doesn't disappear unless we change page. This is not a normal behavior in all the other SE communities.

Comment: I thought they fixed this but I guess not https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345885/323179

Comment: I don't think this is specific to Google Chrome - I have the problem in Firefox as well

Comment: I have seen it in Microsoft Edge, and Firefox, so it's not specific to Chrome.

Comment: Duplicate of [Achievements dropdown is broken on SE.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306452/achievements-dropdown-is-broken-on-se-com).