# Achievements icon is always highlighted on stackexchange.com when there is reputation change, even without any new achievements

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com, achievements-dialog

This is what I see now here on MSE, and any other SE site:

[image: top bar achievements icon showing +10 on sites]

And this is what I see on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/):

[image: top bar achievements icon showing +10 and highlighted on se.com]

Note the subtle difference: se.com showing the icon itself highlighted green, as if there is new achievement, even though there isn't any. Only reputation change. Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Already reported: [Achievement and inbox dropdowns aren't cleared after clicking, on https://stackexchange.com](/q/306452/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon somewhat different, the other report is about rep change not being cleared, this bug report is only about the highlight being incorrect. It's all bugged, but bugs are different enough to justify different reports. IMO.

Comment: I very much doubt this makes a difference.

Comment: @SebastianSimon fair, I can't force you to agree. And it's not like it will be fixed anyway, I report only by force of habit. (In the distant past SE used to actually fix such minor bugs, but alas, it was fully stopped few years ago, and they work only according to "roadmaps" that sadly has no place for user reported bugs.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reputation +n doesn't disappear from the achievements after reading it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345885/282094) (deferred)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306452/282094

Comment: @Rob no, it's the same as Sebastian dupe. Would close as dupe, but since it somehow got red tag, better not touch it. :)

Comment: Sha, normally you would want to: 1st **write** your question to clarify how it differs from similar questions found while researching any potential duplicates, and 2nd when duplicates are proposed you would then **edit** to clarify the difference between our different duplicates and the bug you see today. --- Put another way, answering in a comment doesn't get your post removed from the review queue.

Comment: @Rob normally I would agree. But these days I just can't find the energy; As I said here earlier reported this out of sheer habit when noticing the bug, it's not like I expect it to ever be fixed. So I honestly don't care if this will be closed. (And since I disagree with existing dupe suggestion, not going to close it myself either.)